# Understanding basic IP routing in linux

Tags: networking, ip

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.24    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.25.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.25    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I'm trying to understand how linux routing works.

Packets come and go from devices/ifaces, which are, in this case, `eth0`, `eth1`, `eth2`. So Ip packets come and go from these devices, and possibly other devices like `tun` devices.

Let's say that an IP packet arrives at `eth1`. IP source: 192.168.1.1, IP destination: 199.178.167.431. Since this address is outside of the Genmask for `eth1`, linux will try to send it through the default gateway.

Let's say that an IP packet arrives at `eth1`. IP source: 192.168.1.1, IP destination: 192.168.1.2. Since this address is on the genmask for `eth1`, where will linux send this packet to? From which device?

Let's say that an IP packet arrives at `eth0`. There are two `eth0` entries, so which one does Linux use to route this packet? Also, I don't have idea of the source and destination that this packet could have. Can anyone give an example?

Comment: Nope. 192.168.1.1 will be rejected on eth1 because it is outside of it's network scope. System will only accept 192.168.1.1 on eth0 (i matches interface eth0 network).
Decision in simple routing is based on networks on interfaces. Whatever matches network on interface is being routed to this very interface and forwarded (assuming forwarding is enabled). If there is no match to local networks then packet is sent to default gateway ( 192.168.1.25 through eth0 in your case) and this very default gateway is deciding what to do next with packet.

Comment: A packet from 192.168.1.1 on an iface with an impossible source address is known as a martian (which is usually silently dropped..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I suggest you read a foundation text about TCP/IP and routing tables.

> Let's say that an IP packet arrives at eth1. IP source: 192.168.1.1, IP destination: 199.178.167.431. Since this address is outside of the Genmask for eth1, linux will try to send it through the default gateway.

Packet is discarded since destination IP does not match the interface's definition;

> Let's say that an IP packet arrives at eth1. IP source: 192.168.1.1, IP destination: 192.168.1.2. Since this address is on the genmask for eth1, where will linux send this packet to? From which device?

Packet is discarded since destination IP does not match the interface's definition;

> Let's say that an IP packet arrives at eth0. There are two eth0 entries, so which one does Linux use to route this packet? Also, I don't have idea of the source and destination that this packet could have. Can anyone give an example?

There's only one entry that defines the interface's layer 3 configuration (`192.168.1.24    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 eth0`) so there would be no ambiguity. What you are seeing as well is that the default gateway maps to an IP address that is local to interface `eth0` but this is a route that is used when all others fail, so it does not quite match up to your question.

In the routing process, the kernel always matches from more to less specific route definitions. So if a packet is to be forwarded to `10.1.2.3` and you have 2 route definitions `10.1.0.0/16` to `eth3` and `10.1.2.0/24` to `eth4`, the packet will leave via `eth4` because that is the most specific route that matches the destination.

Answer (score 0):

It's not specific to linux, it's just IP routing rules

I begin with eth1 and eth2, the simplest case.

With the kernel routing table provided for eth1, destination is `192.168.0.0` and netmask `255.255.255.0`. That means that eth1 is in the network having the address `192.168.0`, each computer on the network having an address from 1 to 254; 0 and 255 have special meaning: the first address of a network is the network address, the last is the broadcast address. Each computer therefore has a complet address "network address"."computer address": eg 192.168.0.45 with 255.255.255.0 netmask is the computer address 45 in the 192.168.0 network.
Without a gateway on this interface, the only ip packets that the interface will accept are of this form. There is therefore no packet routing with source ip 192.168.1.1: This address is not in the 192.168.0.0 network and ip packet is discarded.

It is the same with eth2 with the difference that the network has the address 192.168.25.0

For eth0, there is 2 routes. The first one (destination 192.168.1.24, mask 255.255.255.252, no gateway) is for the local network, the second one (destination 0.0.0.0, mask 0.0.0.0, gateway 192.168.1.25) is the "default" route. This route means "if you don't know what to do with a specific packet, send it through 192.168.1.25". This network has a mask of 255.255.255.252. 252 is binary 11111100 and this network had 4 address: 192.168.1.24 (network address), 192.168.1.25 (gateway address, we see this in the routing table), 192.168.1.26 (free address), 192.168.1.27 (broadcast address). It's not hard to guess eth0 has IP address 192.168.1.26.

In any case, the routes are used internally to answer the question "where I send this packet". Assuming your kernel had routing enabled (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` set to 1) we can have this différent case:

- packet with ip source `192.168.1.1` arrive on eth1 (network 192.168.0.0); packet is discarded
- packet with ip source `192.168.0.45` arrive on eth1 (network 192.168.0.0) with ip destination `192.168.25.32`. The packet is accepted by the kernel, and according to the routing table, is output through eth2
- packet with ip source `192.168.0.45` arrive on eth1 (network 192.168.0.0) with ip destination `97.67.25.49`. The packet is accepted by the kernel, but the kernel don't know this particular network and according to the routing table, send through eth0 for 192.168.1.25 (the gateway) the ip packet.
- packet with ip source `192.168.0.45` arrive on eth1 (network 192.168.0.0) with ip destination `192.168.1.1`. The packet is accepted by the kernel, but the kernel don't know this particular network (he knows 192.168.1.24/30, which does not contain 192.168.1.1) and according to the routing table, send through eth0 for 192.168.1.25 (the gateway) the ip packet.

Answer (score 0):

Routing a packet is not dependent on which interface it came in on (well, at least not using normal "non-advanced" routing). The packet might have been generated by a process on the host, in which case it wouldn't have been received from the network at all. Only hosts that act as routers forward packets, i.e. resend incoming packets if they are not destined for them. Servers and workstations usually have forwarding disabled, in which case they drop incoming packets that are not destined for them.

How an outgoing packet is routed works the same way regardless if the packet is locally generated or forwarded: the routing table is consulted, and the best route (with the "longest prefix match") is selected. If the destination host is on a directly connected network, the packet is sent directly to the destination host, otherwise the packet is sent to a router on the local network. The address of this router is found in the "Gateway" column in the matching row of the routing table.

> Let's say that an IP packet arrives at eth1. IP source: 192.168.1.1,
>   IP destination: 199.178.167.431. Since this address is outside of the
>   Genmask for eth1, linux will try to send it through the default
>   gateway.

Your examples are a bit contrived; in the real world a packet with this source address wouldn't come in on interface `eth1`, because the address belongs to the network connected to interface `eth0`. If this happens, something is badly misconfigured. This is also why the packet is dropped.

The netmask for the network on the incoming interface (`eth1` in your example) also does not affect how the packet is routed, only the routing table plays a part in that. In general, in "classic" routing the choice of the next hop is always based on looking forward, not the past history of the packet (like which interface, if any, it came in on.)